# K8s Pod Topology Spread is not respected after rollout?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to spread my `ingress-nginx-controller` pods such that:

- Each availability zone has the same # of pods (+- 1).
- Pods prefer Nodes that currently run the least pods.

Following other questions here, I have set up Pod Topology Spread Constraints in my pod deployment:

```
      replicas: 4
      topologySpreadConstraints:
      - labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
        whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
      - labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
```

I currently have 2 Nodes, each in a different availability zone:

```
$ kubectl get nodes --label-columns=topology.kubernetes.io/zone,kubernetes.io/hostname
NAME                            STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   ZONE         HOSTNAME
ip-{{node1}}.compute.internal   Ready    node                   136m   v1.20.2   us-west-2a   ip-{{node1}}.compute.internal
ip-{{node2}}.compute.internal   Ready    node                   20h    v1.20.2   us-west-2b   ip-{{node2}}.compute.internal
```

After running `kubectl rollout restart` for that deployment, I get 3 pods in one Node, and 1 pod in the other, which has a skew of `2 > 1`:

```
$ kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx | grep 'Node:'
Node:         ip-{{node1}}.compute.internal/{{node1}}
Node:         ip-{{node2}}.compute.internal/{{node2}}
Node:         ip-{{node1}}.compute.internal/{{node1}}
Node:         ip-{{node1}}.compute.internal/{{node1}}
```

Why is my constraint not respected? How can I debug the pod scheduler?

My kubectl version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.0-beta.0.607+269d62d895c297", GitCommit:"269d62d895c29743931bfaaec6e8d37ced43c35f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-05T22:28:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.16", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:20:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: My current theory is that Pod Spread Topologies also account for pods from a previous rollout. After all new pods are running, k8s would terminate some previous rollout pods which could cause the imbalance.

Comment: Can you provide your pod yaml? or even better if deployment yaml

Comment: @SahadatHossain here, it's an amazon nginx-ingress manifest with very few edits: https://gist.github.com/roim/64de522ec887409ad5c6cf4ac0343de0

I did find others describing the same issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98215

I was able to get correct topologies by scaling my deployment to 1 replica, then up to 4 again. I might look into kubernetes descheduler as a mitigation if bad topology after rollouts is really the root cause.

Comment: @roim could you please tell how your cluster was created? Is it a self-managed solution or a provider-managed (Is the `amazon nginx-ingress` telling that this is `EKS` by any chance)? Also, as a workaround have you considered using `Daemonset`? The difference would be that instead of a `Pod` in a zone there would be `Pod` on each `Node`.

Comment: @DawidKruk cluster is self hosted, created with kOps, and I installed the nginx-ingress with their official manifest for AWS (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/). I'll take a look at a Daemonset, that sounds promising

Comment: @roim I see that the github issue that you've referenced had no updates in a few days. Have you made any progress on the issue? Any luck on the `Daemonset` I've told you about?

Comment: @DawidKruk daemonset worked and was easy enough. It won't work for our deployments with several pods per node, but there are mitigations there (descheduler) and it should self resolve as the cluster grows. If you want to post about daemonsets as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl rollout restart` spins up new pods and then terminate old pods **after** all the new pods are up and running.

From the pod topology spread constraints [known limitations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#known-limitations) section, constraints don't remain satisfied when pods are removed and the recommended mitigation is now to use [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler) , which you already seemed to have been using from your comment.

Comment: Making this the accepted answer since it directly answers my question. The other answers provide workarounds and are still useful though.

Answer (score 3):

In Kubernetes 1.25, you can now use the alpha feature `matchLabelKeys` to resolve this issue. Because there is an automatically generated `pod-template-hash` for each version of a deployment added to each pod, that and your app specific label can provide the hashed value to prevent mis-scheduling.

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
      labelSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my_app
      matchLabelKeys:
        - pod-template-hash
```

> matchLabelKeys is a list of pod label keys to select the pods over
> which spreading will be calculated. The keys are used to lookup values
> from the pod labels, those key-value labels are ANDed with
> labelSelector to select the group of existing pods over which
> spreading will be calculated for the incoming pod. Keys that don't
> exist in the pod labels will be ignored. A null or empty list means
> only match against the labelSelector.
>
> With matchLabelKeys, users don't need to update the pod.spec between
> different revisions. The controller/operator just needs to set
> different values to the same label key for different revisions. The
> scheduler will assume the values automatically based on
> matchLabelKeys. For example, if users use Deployment, they can use the
> label keyed with pod-template-hash, which is added automatically by
> the Deployment controller, to distinguish between different revisions
> in a single Deployment.
>
> Note: The matchLabelKeys field is an alpha field added in 1.25. You
> have to enable the MatchLabelKeysInPodTopologySpread feature gate in
> order to use it.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/)

Answer (score 2):

Giving more visibility on the comment:

> Daemonset worked and was easy enough. It won't work for our deployments with several pods per node, but there are mitigations there (descheduler) and it should self resolve as the cluster grows.

**Please consider this answer as a workaround**:

> **A *DaemonSet* ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod.** As nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/)*

An example of it could be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx 
    spec:
      #nodeSelector: 
          #schedule: here 
      tolerations:
      # this toleration is to have the daemonset runnable on master nodes
      # remove it if your masters can't run pods
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

This definition will spawn a `Pod` on each `Node` in the cluster. You can further limit the `Pod` scheduling by specifying a `nodeSelector`.

Assuming that you have some controller/logic responsible for tagging the nodes with a specific label you can schedule `Pods` on specific Nodes. The part responsible for it is commented out in above manifest:

```
      nodeSelector: 
          schedule: here
```

The nodes (`raven-sgdm` and `raven-xvvw` are labeled): :

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
raven-6k6m   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.20
raven-sgdm   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.20
raven-xvvw   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.20
```

The `Daemonset`:

```
NAME    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
nginx   2         2         2       2            2           schedule=here   99m
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Pod topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Issues: 98215](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98215)*

Comment: This is a nice workaround as the present K8s issue is much more common when your # of pods is low (similar to the cardinality of the topology you select), so running 1 pod per node makes sense. If you can't use a daemonset because you want several pods per node, then the issue described here likely doesn't apply anyways.

Answer (score 1):

At certain moment in time the skew will be proper.

But when the pods that are to be removed will be removed the skew might be skewed :)

Essentially you are facing the limitation described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/):

```
Scaling down a Deployment may result in imbalanced Pods distribution.
```

One simple workaround I apply is **scale it down + restart/deploy + scale it up**.

Then the skew is perfectly fine!

Comment: I would think, using OrderedReady StatefulSet could overcome this limitation during scale-in. Right?